# Some translations have a longer version

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 32:43 (NASB)

> Rejoice, you nations, with His people; For He will avenge the blood of His servants, And will return vengeance on His adversaries, And will atone for His land and His people

in NIV

> Rejoice, you nations, with his people, for he will avenge the blood of his servants; he will take vengeance on his enemies and make atonement for his land and people.

And in KJV

> Rejoice, O ye nations, with his people: for he will avenge the blood of his servants, and will render vengeance to his adversaries, and will be merciful unto his land, and to his people.

Then, in BSB

> Rejoice, O heavens, with Him, and let all God’s angels worship Him. Rejoice, O nations, with His people; for He will avenge the blood of His children. He will take vengeance on His adversaries and repay those who hate Him; He will cleanse His land and His people.

and in NLT

> Rejoice with him, you heavens, and let all of God’s angels worship him. Rejoice with his people, you Gentiles, and let all the angels be strengthened in him. For he will avenge the blood of his children; he will take revenge against his enemies. He will repay those who hate him and cleanse his people’s land.

What makes the last two translations have a longer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple to answer.

The NIV and NASB and similar strictly follow the Masoretic Hebrew text.

A few others such as NLT & BSB, in this case, include an extra part of the text according to the Greek translation known as the Septuagint or LXX.  The LXX adds

> Rejoice, O heavens, with Him, and let all God’s angels worship Him.

Because this extra text is quoted in Hebrews 1:6, these versions presumably feel some justification to include the addition to the Masoretic text (MT).  However, these version usually draw attention to the fact that they have included this extra from the LXX in a footnote, as here.

NOTE - the LXX often differs from the MT for a variety of reasons only some of which are understood.

Comment: Deuteronomy Is one of the very few places where **both** the early Septuagint - *and* - the Dead Sea scrolls differ from the Masoretic text.